# How to ignore Nan value in pandas data frame to compute defined distance matrix for hierarchical clustering

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, distance, nan

I have some time series dataset which I store it in pandas `dataframe`. These time series are varying in length, so some elements are `Nan`. I should remove these `Nan` value in order to compute distance matrics of these time series.

To compute the distance matric I use `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` and `mlpy.dtw_std` as follow:

```
print(type(ctl))    
dm = pdist ( ctl,lambda u,v: mlpy.dtw_std ( u.dropna(),v.dropna(),dist_only=True ))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
line 50, in <lambda>
    dm = pdist ( ctl,lambda u,v: mlpy.dtw_std ( u.dropna(),v.dropna(),dist_only=True ))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dropna'
```

Also removing `Nan` value in lambda is a time-consuming idea, how can I provide the data in order to compute distance matrix for time series with different length.

Edit:
Here is the dataset:

```
           0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8  \
0      143.0  -207.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0   127.0   
1      127.0  -127.0   143.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0   
2      143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0   127.0   
3      143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0   127.0   
4      143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0   127.0   
5      143.0  -207.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0     NaN   
6      143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0   127.0   
7      143.0  -207.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0   127.0   
8      143.0  -207.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0     NaN   
9      127.0  -127.0   143.0   127.0  -143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
10     143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0     NaN   
11     143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0     NaN   
12     143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0   127.0   
13     127.0  -127.0   143.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0   
14     143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   143.0     NaN   
15     127.0   143.0  -143.0  -191.0   143.0  -191.0   143.0   143.0  -159.0   
16     328.0  -207.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1142.0     NaN   
17    -207.0   143.0   248.0  -431.0   143.0  -287.0   143.0   143.0  -383.0   
18     376.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0   
19     328.0  -207.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0   
20     328.0  -207.0 -1475.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0   
21     392.0 -1475.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1142.0     NaN     NaN   
22     127.0  -127.0   143.0  -255.0   143.0   248.0  -642.0   143.0  -383.0   
23    -271.0   143.0   248.0  -495.0  -399.0   232.0   143.0  -399.0   143.0   
24    -255.0   143.0   248.0  -399.0   143.0  -383.0   143.0   143.0  -383.0   
25     376.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0   
26    -271.0   143.0   248.0  -463.0   143.0  -399.0   143.0   143.0  -399.0   
27     328.0  -207.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0   
28    -255.0   143.0   248.0  -447.0   143.0  -399.0   143.0   143.0  -383.0   
29     392.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0 -1474.0  -510.0   
...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   
17189  127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0   
17190  127.0  -143.0   127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0   
17191  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   
17192  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   
17193  127.0  -143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0     NaN   
17194  127.0  -143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0     NaN   
17195  127.0  -143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0     NaN   
17196  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0   127.0  -143.0     NaN   
17197  127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0   
17198  127.0  -431.0   143.0   200.0  -191.0  -431.0   143.0     NaN     NaN   
17199  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   
17200  127.0  -143.0   127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0   
17201  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -143.0     NaN   
17202 -143.0   143.0   127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0   
17203  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0   127.0  -143.0     NaN   
17204  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   
17205  127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0   
17206  127.0  -127.0   143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   
17207  127.0  -143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0     NaN   
17208  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -143.0     NaN   
17209  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0  -143.0   143.0   127.0   
17210  127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0   
17211  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   
17212  127.0  -143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0     NaN   
17213  127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0   
17214  127.0  -127.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   
17215  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   
17216  127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0     NaN     NaN     NaN   
17217  127.0  -143.0   127.0  -431.0   143.0   127.0  -463.0   143.0     NaN   
17218  127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -447.0   143.0   127.0  -479.0   143.0   

            9 ...  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  
0      -143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
1      -143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2      -127.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
3      -143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
4      -143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
5         NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
6      -143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
7      -143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
8         NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
9         NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
10        NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
11        NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
12     -143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
13     -159.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
14        NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
15      143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
16        NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17      143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
18     -974.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
19    -1166.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
20    -1166.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
21        NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
22      143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
23      127.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
24      143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
25     -974.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
26      143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
27    -1166.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
28      143.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
29        NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
...       ... ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  
17189     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17190  -463.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17191     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17192     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17193     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17194     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17195     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17196     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17197     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17198     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17199     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17200  -479.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17201     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17202  -463.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17203     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17204     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17205     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17206     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17207     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17208     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17209  -127.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17210     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17211     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17212     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17213   127.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17214   127.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17215     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17216     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17217     NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  
17218   127.0 ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  

[17219 rows x 30 columns]
```

Edit2:
I came up with following to remove nan and compute the distance matrix:

```
ctlf=pd.Series ( [np.array ( e )[~np.isnan ( e )] for e in ctl.values] )
    n =  len(ctlf)
    distanceMatrix = [[0 for i in range ( n )] for j in range ( n )]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i,n):
            distanceMatrix[i][j]=distanceMatrix[j][i]=mlpy.dtw_std ( ctlf[i],ctlf[j],dist_only=True )
```

but I need the distance matrix in the form of the 1d compressed distance matrix, where it must be a (n 2) sized vector where n is the number of original observations paired in the distance matrix. Which Then I could pass it to `hac.linkage(distanceMatrix, method='average')` in order to cluster the dataset.

Edit3 : Here is the story behind it:

I have a dataset of the time-dependent samples, which I want to run agglomerative hierarchical clustering on them. I have found that Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) is a useful method to find alignments between two time series which may vary in time or speed.

I have found `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` library in order to cluster my data using defined metrics 'mlpy.dtw_std '.

My dataset is stored in `pandas dataframe`. The samples are waring in size, so there are `nan` value in the `dataframe` which should be ignored when computing `mlpy.dtw_std`.

To provide data for `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(distanceMatrix, method='average')` I need a distance matrix in the form of the 1d compressed distance matrix, where it must be a (n 2) sized vector where n is the number of original observations paired in the distance matrix.

Comment: I have added the dataset.

Comment: Doesn't dropping NaNs result in incorrect distances? You're misaligning your data points that way.

Comment: Also, can you give us an idea of what your expected result is, for, say, a dataset of 10 rows and 5 columns with NaNs in it.

Comment: In the case keeping NaNs, I get inf distance. The Nan in dataset are because of the length.

Comment: I need the `mlpy.dtw_std` as distance metric, what is the function you suggest?!

Comment: The result which i need is in the form of the 1d compressed distance matrix, where it must be a (n 2) sized vector where n is the number of original observations paired in the distance matrix.

Comment: I don't know how to use this function in a vectorised manner, as I know nothing about it or how it works.

Comment: It is Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) which use to compute time series distances. By the way, I have computed distance matrix by iterating over samples, how can I convert it to the acceptable format of the `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage`

Comment: I've retagged your question, now all you've to do is wait for someone who knows more than me to come by and answer your question. If that doesn't happen, put a bounty on your question. Should work. Good luck.

Comment: in your title versus question context, I'm slightly confused. What do you mean by "ignore NaN?" Either using 0 in-place, skip the calculation, or another method? Also - as one who is not familiar with this area of data - perhaps using less sample data, and more expected outcome along explanation, you may get more "Bites" in regards to people who can help you.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it clarifies my problem.